# Laravel update file on AWS s3 bucket

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

So currently I can store files in the AWS s3 bucket, but I can't update the file
so far this is what I tried  please help!.

```
  if($request->hasFile('uploadURL')) {
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('uploadURL')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('uploadURL')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore= $filename.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('uploadURL')->storeAs('public/uploads', $fileNameToStore, 's3');
       
         
        } else {
            $fileNameToStore = 'noimage.jpg';
        }

        $upload = new Uploads;
        $upload->description = $request->input('description');
        $upload->student_id = $request->input('student_id');
        $upload->uploadURL = $fileNameToStore;
        $evidence->update($request->all());
```

Comment: What do you mean update?

Comment: so by update I mean remove that file and upload a new file

Comment: Ok so delete it and then upload it again… I don’t see the issue here

Comment: I don't know how to get that specific file from the bucket since I change the name when I store it 

Comment: If you change the name to something, how do you want to get the file? You need some way of identifying the file - there's actually no question in your question.

Comment: When you store the image in the bucket, create a database entry for it and store the path/file name in there

Answer (score 0):

thank you all , problem solved

```
if ($request->hasFile('uploadURL')) {

            Storage::disk('s3')->delete('public/uploads/' . $evidence->uploadURL);
            // Get filename with the extension
            $filenameWithExt = $request->file('uploadURL')->getClientOriginalName();
            // Get just filename
            $filename = pathinfo($filenameWithExt, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
            // Get just ext
            $extension = $request->file('uploadURL')->getClientOriginalExtension();
            // Filename to store
            $fileNameToStore = $filename . '_' . time() . '.' . $extension;
            // Upload Image
            $path = $request->file('uploadURL')->storeAs('public/uploads', $fileNameToStore, 's3');

        } else {

            if ($evidence->uploadURL != 'noimage.jpg') {
                $fileNameToStore = $evidence->uploadURL;
            }
        }

        $upload = new Uploads;
        $upload->description = $request->input('description');
        $upload->student_id = $request->input('student_id');
        $upload->uploadURL = $fileNameToStore;
        $evidence->update($upload->toArray());
```